# Alternative words and phrases for "school finishing" in this context

Tags: word-request, alternatives

"My school finishes at 4pm."

What can be the alternatives for "finish"?

Comment: *'gets over at, the day at school ends at, am done with school for the day at...'*

Comment: Would "concludes" suffice?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few possibilities. Some are relatively local dialect things.

- "My school day ends at 4pm"
- "My school kicks out at 4pm"
- "My school ends classes/lessons at 4pm" (which of *classes* or *lessons* you use depends on dialect)
- "My school closes at 4pm" (this may be taken to mean there are no after-school activities, or that there are, and the normal schoolday ends earlier than 4pm - and the after-school stuff finished by 4pm)
- "I finish school at 4pm" (or *lessons* or *classes* at 4pm)
- "I get out of school at 4pm"

The last two change the subject to the speaker, rather than the school, but in a lot of situations would be more natural, in my experience.